# Convergence Of A Complicated Sequence

Tags: calculus

Consider a sequence $a_n$, $$\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, \frac{2}{4}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{1}{5}, ......... $$. Now consider $0 \leq a < b \leq 1$. Also $N(n, a, b)$ denote the number of $j \leq n$ such that $a_j$ lies in $[a, b]$. Prove that for a given $a, b$ the sequence $$\frac{N(n, a, b)}{n}$$ converges to $b-a$.
$$$$Let $k^{th}$ group be the group of numbers of the sequence with denominators $k$. Now looking at the sequence consider any $n$ then either $a_n$ is the last number of some $p^{th}$ group or it lies in some $q^{th}$ group. Suppose $a_n$ lies in some $q^{th}$ group then denominator of the last number of the group say $r$ previous to the group to which $a_n$ belongs satisfies the inequality $$\frac{r^2-r}{2} \leq n$$ and hence $$r \leq \frac{1+\sqrt{8n+1}}{2}$$ but as $r$ is the denominator of the last number in the group previous to the group to which $a_n$ belongs so we have $$r=[\frac{1+\sqrt{8n+1}}{2}]$$ where $[x]$ is the greatest integer function. Let us denote $$p_n=[\frac{1+\sqrt{8n+1}}{2}]$$. Suppose $a_n$ lies in some $q^{th}$ group, then as calculated above the denominator of that group i.e $q=p_n+1$. Now let $\frac{y}{p_n+1}$ be the largest number in the $q^{th}$ group which lies in $[a, b]$ and let $\frac{x}{p_n+1}$ be the smallest such number then we have the inequality $$\frac{y-x}{p_n+1} \leq b-a => y-x \leq (b-a)(p_n+1)$$. Also we have $$\frac{y+1}{p_n+1}>b$$ and $$\frac{x-1}{p_n+1}<a$$ and hence we have the inequality $$b-a < \frac{y-x+2}{p_n+1} =>(b-a)(p_n+1) < y-x+2$$ and as $y$ and $x$ are positive integers hence we get the inequality $$y-x \leq [(p_n+1)(b-a)] \leq y-x+1$$ and hence we have $$[(p_n+1)(b-a)] \leq y-x+1 \leq [(p_n+1)(b-a)]+1$$, where $[x]$ is the greatest integer function. Also it is easy to see that the number of terms is the sequence in the $(p_n+1)^{th}$ group which lie in $[a, b]$ is equal to $y-x+1$ and hence the total number of such terms say $S$ from $1st$ group to the $(p_n+1)^{th}$ group satisfies the inequality $$[(p_n+1)(b-a)]+[(p_n)(b-a)]+......+[(2)(b-a)] \leq S \leq [(p_n+1)(b-a)]+1+[(p_n)(b-a)]+1+......+[(2)(b-a)]+1$$. Now consider the term $$\frac{[(p_n+1)(b-a)]+[(p_n)(b-a)]+......+[(2)(b-a)]}{n}=\frac{[([\frac{1+\sqrt{8n+1}}{2}]+1)(b-a)]+[([\frac{1+\sqrt{8n+1}}{2}])(b-a)]+.....+[(2)(b-a)]}{n}$$, it is easy to show using sandwich Theorem that this expression converges to $b-a$ as $n$ tends to infinity. Also similarly we can prove using sandwich Theorem that the expression $$[(p_n+1)(b-a)]+1+[(p_n)(b-a)]+1+......+[(2)(b-a)]+1$$ also converges to $b-a$ as $n$ tends to infinity. And as $\frac{S}{n}$ is sandwiched between these two expressions so it also converges to $b-a$ and henc $$\frac{N(n, a, b)}{n}=\frac{S}{n}$$ converges to $b-a$. Similarly we can show this in the case when $a_n$ is the last number of some $p^{th}$ group.
$$$$Is My Proof Correct??